# Mysql se bloquea sin motivo

Tags: mysql, rendimiento

Tengo un problemilla con un servidor MySQL que tengo, he intentado buscar una solución sin éxito. Tras activar los logs he logrado encontrar donde ocurre, pero sigo sin saber porque ni como solucionarlo.

```
# administrator command: Prepare;
# Time: 200506 14:05:53
# User@Host: ---[---] @  [127.0.0.1]
# Thread_id: 4480  Schema: micole  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 10.970731  Lock_time: 2.241522  Rows_sent: 5  Rows_examined: 5
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 152
SET timestamp=1588766753;
select `name` as `label` from `schoolprice`;
```

La tabla seleccionada tan solo tiene 5 filas y aún así el tiempo es de 10.9 segundos y el bloqueo de 2.24.

Este bloqueo no ocurre siempre, es algo que pasa de forma eventual de vez en cuando, lo que me hace pensar que hay algo en la configuración de mi servidor que no está bien.

Aquí dejo otra query que también va horriblementa mal.

```
# administrator command: Prepare;
# User@Host: ---[---] @  [---------]
# Thread_id: 4423  Schema: micole  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 116.216689  Lock_time: 8.979123  Rows_sent: 532  Rows_examined: 532
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 15509
SET timestamp=1588766779;
SHOW STATUS;
```

Espero que podáis ayudarme, gracias!

Comment: Qué versión de MySQL usas?

Comment: Ejecuta la sentencia ``SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`` y nos compartes la salida